# How to check login detail from a text file of username and passwords? PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, authentication

I have a form that requires users to enter a username and password. There is a text file of registered usernames and passwords. How can I get the login.php to check if the username exists in file and that the corresponding password exists. And if so to inform user and return to index.php with the name of user displayed on top of page?
The text file has 4 elements for each user separated by a comma: fullname, email, username and password.

The function I have written so far is:

```
function validate_fname() {
    global $fname, $validated, $errors_detected;
    if (!empty($_POST['fname']))    {
        $trimmed = trim($_POST['fname']);
        if  (strlen($trimmed)<=150  && preg_match('/\\s/', $trimmed))       {
            $validated['fullname'] = $_POST['fname'];
            $fname = htmlentities($_POST['fname']);
            return "<p>You entered full name: $fname</p>";  
    }   else    {
            $errors_detected = true;
            return "<p>Full name must be no more than 150 characters and must contain one space.</p>";      }
    }
    else {
            $errors_detected = true;
            return "<p>Field not submitted!</p>";
    }   
}
```

and the login.php is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/header.php';
require_once 'functions.php';
?>
    <title>Login</title>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <br />
    <a  href="index.php">Home</a> |
    <a  href="aboutus.php">About Us</a> |
    <a  href="privatepage.php">Members Area</a> |
    <a  href="register.php">Register</a> |
    <br /><br />
    <?php
    $self = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $uname = '';
    $pw = '';
    $validation;//Holds success or failure messages.
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  //Only executes functions when form is submitted.
            $validation = validate_logon();
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $self; ?>" method="post">  <!--Sets up form-->
        <fieldset>
        <p>Please enter your username and password</p>
        <legend>Login</legend>
            <?php
                include 'includes/logindetails.php';
            ?>
            <div>            
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br />
    New users click on register link on top of page; 
</body>
</html>
```

Please note logindetails.php just has the text to create two form fields for username and password.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I believe a database is better suited for this situation. Holding usernames and passwords in a text file is **never** a good idea. Here's a good overview of getting started in MYSQL Database for PHP http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: It is for an assignment and I am not allowed use of database but only a text file.

Answer (score 0):

There is function that works like that way but, this is highly NOT recommended at all when it comes to storing passwords.  There are many smart dudes out there that can easily break into an app like that design you are asking.

Comment: This is good for you for school-wise assignment then: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/830024-php-login-using-data-from-a-text-file/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fopen() and fread().

Taken from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

?>
```

Then maybe use `explode(' ', $contents)` to read the items into array.

```
<?php
$details = explode(' ', $contents);
foreach($details as $value){
      if($uname === $value){
           return 'Match found';
      }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Read : https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php